# How to combine tables of different columns into 1 result set and make all attributes of same pk in 1 row with 1 SQL statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a problems in combining tables

I have 2 table:
t1:

```
id   |   name
----- ---------
1    |   'foo'
2    |   'bar'
```

t2:

```
id    |   type
------ ---------
1     |  'type1'
3     |  'type2'
```

I want to combine those tables into 1 result set and make all attributes of same primary key in 1 row. And with single SQL statement in Oracle. The primary key column with the same name (id in the sample) can't appear twice

The result should be:

```
id   |   name  |  type
----- --------- ---------
1    |   'foo' |  'type1'
2    |   'bar' |   null
3    |    null |  'type2'
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas and responses.

Update:
I tried Ani Menon's out join statement, but not 100% the expected result.  The outer join gives null value if id exists in t1 but not in t2.

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t2.type
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id;
```

Returns

```
id   |   name  |  type
----- --------- ---------
1    |   'foo' |  'type1'
2    |   'bar' |   null
null |    null |  'type2'
```

Comment: Please share what you tried so far?

Comment: I don't have any idea by myself. I tried the outer join replied by Ani Menon. But didn't get what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to Ani's answer, but won't give you the `null` id:

```
select coalesce(table1.id, table2.id) as id, table1.name, table2.type
  from table1 full outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a full outer join:

```
SELECT table1.id,table1.name,table2.type
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;
```

**Edit:**

Use `coalesce(table1.id,table2.id)` in place of `table1.id` in the query.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but the result is a slightly different. The outer join gives null value if id exists in table1 but not in table2.

Comment: You may use coalesce(col1 ,col2) to pick which ever is available. Answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t2.type
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
union
select t2.id, t1.name, t2.type
from t2
left outer join t1 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting to guess the solution without testing. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

might now be the optimal solution but this will work.

```
select allIDs.id, t1.name, t2.type
    (select id from t1
    union
    select id from t2) allIDs left outer join t1 on allIDs.id = t1.id left outer join t2 on allIDs.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

tested in sql server worked.

```
   create table t1 (
    id int,
    name varchar(25)
)


create table t2
(
    id int,
    type varchar(25)
)

insert into t1
values(1, 'fool'),
    (2,'bar')

insert into t2
values(1,'type1'),
    (3,'type2')

select id, MAX(name) name, MAX(type) type from(
select id, name, null type from t1
union all
select id, null name, type from t2) combine group by id
```